# Pricing values and storing them to access on checkout page

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently having troubles in finding a way where I can price my two radio buttons and when clicked on one of them, the price goes to the checkout page which a user can later access once completed the booking page.

So in steps:

1. User clicks on standard or first class ticket.
2. User clicks on the input value of “number” and chooses how many adults and child tickets they need (the number of adults and children are multiplied by the ticket price).
3. The total price is given below as a input type “text”.
4. User then clicks on the checkout button which will direct them to the checkout page.
5. User will be able to see individually the number of tickets bought for adults and child also their prices and total.

Now I have managed to give the standard and First class a price by using variables, now this next step I am confused at.

```js
function standardfunction() {

  var Type1 = document.getElementById('Standard').value;
  var adult = document.getElementById('adult').value;
  var child = document.getElementById('child').value;


  var Total_Cost
  var Type1 = 6
  var adult = 1
  var child = 0.5

  alert(Total_Cost = adult * Type1);

}

function firstclassfunction() {

  var Type2 = document.getElementById('First-Class').value;
  var adult = document.getElementById('adult').value;
  var child = document.getElementById('child').value;

  var Total_Cost
  var Type2 = 10
  var adult = 1
  var child = 0.5
  alert(Total_Cost = adult * Type2);

}
```

```html
<label for="Adult-ticket" class="center-label">Adults(+16)</label>
    <input type="number" id="adult" name="user_adult">

    <label for="child-ticket" class="center-label">Child</label>
    <input type="number" id="child" name="user_child">
    
    <input type="radio" id="Standard" name="Type" value="Standard" onclick="standardfunction()">
    <label class="light" for="Standard">Standard</label><br>
    
    <input type="radio" id="First-Class" name="Type" value="First-Class" onclick="first-classfunction()>
    <label class="light" for="First-Class">First Class</label><br><br>
    <input type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn">
```

Another problem is that how can I price the radio button so that the radio button is the default adult price but when they also had child tickets it gives them as not one full adult ticket but half so:

```
Adult = £6
Child = £3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that input values are recorded as strings and need to be converted to numbers first.

Use `Number` or `parseInt` first to convert to an integer.

You are also declaring the same variables twice, and the second time they override the first. You want to get input from the user, so I deleted the second instances of your variable.

Also

```
alert(Total_Cost = adult *  Type2);
```

isn't proper syntax. It should be

```
alert(adult * Type2);
```

It's also possible to combine the two functions into one

Your HTML code now needs to be modified. You need to run the function when the submit button has been pressed.

```js
function calculateFare() {
    var option = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked')
    var fare = option.getAttribute("value");
    var ad = Number(document.getElementById('adult').value);
    var ch = Number(document.getElementById('child').value);

    var cost = (fare == "Standard") ? (ad * 6) + (ch * 3) : (ad * 10) + (ch * 5);        

    document.getElementById("total-cost").innerHTML = cost;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="Adult-ticket" class="center-label">Adults(+16)</label>
<input type="number" id="adult" name="user_adult">

<label for="child-ticket" class="center-label">Child</label>
<input type="number" id="child" name="user_child">
    
<input type="radio" id="Standard" name="Type" value="Standard">
<label class="light" for="Standard">Standard</label><br>
    
<input type="radio" id="First-Class" name="Type" value="First-Class">
<label class="light" for="First-Class">First Class</label><br><br>
<input type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="calculateFare()">

<p id="total-cost"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this. The only trouble i am having is that when i click on standard it gives me the first-class price. when i click on first-class it also gives em the first-class price. This means it doesnt detect the standard or the standard has the same value... maybe ?

Comment: `alert(Total_Cost = adult * Type2);` _is_ proper syntax, but bad style.